# How to type both username and age?

Tags: c

I want to make a simple console application where it asks me for my age and then username.

First I tried asking for age and when typed, it should ask me for username and after all that it should write my age, age+3 years and my username. However, it just asks me for my age and literally skips asking for my username and returns "Your username is P" or some kind of symbol like P.

Secondly I tried using single line of code: "Type your age first, followed by username", but I'm having little trouble there because I didn't learn that in YT tutorial.

FIRST TRY (doesn't even stop to ask for my username, returns some kind of symbol P)

```
int main(void)
{
    int AGE;
    char USERNAME[20];
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&AGE);
    printf("Now please enter your username: ");
    scanf("%c", &USERNAME);
    printf("You are %d years old.\n", AGE);
    printf("But in 3 years, you will be %d.\n", AGE + 3);
    printf("Your username is %c", USERNAME);
}
```

SECOND TRY (not sure about this one since I'm experimenting, didn't learn how to read two variables in single line)

```
int main(void)
{
    int AGE;
    char USERNAME[20];
    printf("Enter your age and then username:");
    scanf("%d" "%c",&AGE, &USERNAME);
    printf("You are %d years old.\n", AGE);
    printf("But in 3 years, you will be %d.\n", AGE + 3);
    printf("Your username is %c", USERNAME);
}
```

Comment: use %s for string not %c, change that in the scanf and printf functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `%s` for inputting strings with `scanf`. You should also pass a `char *` argument to it when using `%s` (because the string needs to be allocated beforehand). So this would be correct:

```
int main(void)
{
    int age; /* Lowercase variable names */
    char username[20];
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("Now please enter your username: ");
    scanf("%19s", username); /* `%s` for strings and pass a `char *`
                              * make sure to only read 19 characters */
    printf("You are %d years old.\n", age);
    printf("But in 3 years, you will be %d.\n", age + 3);
    printf("Your username is %s", username); /* %s for strings */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But why did I program skip the part when it was asking me for my name? I made a similar program and it literally skips asking for my full name and returns me blank name later.

Comment: @UrosGavrilovic I don't know. Ask another question. It's probably because you're using `%c` instead of `%s`. `%c` doesn't skip whitespace (so it's getting your enter key).